# How does numpy three dimensiona slicing and indexing and ellipsis work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having a hard time understanding how some of numpy's slicing and indexing works

**First one is the following:**

```
>>> x = np.array([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]])
>>> x.shape
(2, 3, 1)
>>> x[1:2]
array([[[4],
        [5],
        [6]]])
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html),

> If the number of objects in the selection tuple is less than N , then
>   : is assumed for any subsequent dimensions.

So does that means `[[1], [2], [3]] , [[4], [5], [6]]` is a 2x3 array itself?

And how does

```
x[1:2]
```

return

```
array([[[4],
        [5],
        [6]]])
```

?

**The second is ellipsis**,

```
>>> x[...,0]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

> Ellipsis expand to the number of : objects needed to make a selection
>   tuple of the same length as x.ndim. There may only be a single
>   ellipsis present.

Why does `[...,0]` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, it means that `x` of shape (2, 3, 1) has 2 slices of `3x1` arrays.

```
In [40]: x
Out[40]: 
array([[[1],
        [2],          # <= slice 1 of shape 3x1
        [3]],

       [[4],
        [5],          # <= slice 2 of shape 3x1
        [6]]])
```

Now, when you execute `x[1:2]`, it just hands you over the first slice but not including the second slice since in Python & NumPy it's always left inclusive and right exclusive (something like half-open interval, i.e. [1,2) )

```
In [42]: x[1:2]
Out[42]: 
array([[[4],
        [5],
        [6]]])
```

This is why you just get the first slice.

For your second question,

```
In [45]: x.ndim
Out[45]: 3
```

So, when you use ellipsis, it just stretches out your array to size 3.

```
In [47]: x[...,0]
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

The above code means, you take both slices from the array x, and stretch it row-wise.

But instead, if you do

```
In [49]: x[0, ..., 0]
Out[49]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Here, you just take the first slice from `x` and stretch it row-wise.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it really helps

Answer (score 0):

Now, when you execute x[1:2], it just hands you over the **first slice**.

My question is shouldn't it be **second slice**. As the output is slice 2

```
In [42]: x[1:2]
Out[42]: 
array([[[4],
        [5],
        [6]]])
```